# Which one is preferable : zmq_send or zmq_msg_send?

Tags: zeromq

I am discovering zeroMQ, and I understand that `zmq_send` sends a buffer and `zmq_msg_send` sends a `zmq_msg_t` message.
It seems to me that it is two different ways of doing the same thing (both can send multi-part messages, etc).

What are the advantages of using `zmq_msg_t` structs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Advantage is simply that your code works on a bit lower-level, closer to the metal, and saves a few CPU-cycles, that **`.zmq_send()`** wrapper spends on preparing the `zmq_msg_t` struct and passing it forward to the ZMQ-internal messaging processing as the `.zmq_msg_send()` does in one step.